# Can you wrap multiple BlockingCollections around a single backing store?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, blockingcollection

I would like to know if it is possible to instantiate multiple BlockingCollections with a single backing store for example :

```
ConcurrentStack<object> theStack = new ConcurrentStack<object>();
BlockingCollection<object> blockingStack1 = new BlockingCollection<object>(theStack);
BlockingCollection<object> blockingStack2 = new BlockingCollection<object>(theStack);
```

The motivation for this enquiry is as follows; `BlockingCollection` requires the invocation of it's Dispose method. This is seamless with the use of a `using` block. However, since a `using` block is not always appropriate ( consider the producer & consumer living not only in different methods but also on different threads ) trying to do the book-keeping required for calling Dispose becomes a lot less trivial and a lot more error-prone. If however, instead of propagating a `BlockingCollection`, you could instead propagate the backing store then a local `BlockingCollection` could be instantiated locally inside a `using` block.

My guess is that you can since there is nothing in the IProducerConsumerCollection interface, the only thing the BlockingCollection relies on, that seems to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use multiple `BlockingCollection`s with the same `IProducerConsumerCollection` safely. Here's some information we have from the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) (which could *maybe* be taken to mean that you can use more than a single `BlockingCollection`):

> Do not modify the underlying collection directly. Use BlockingCollection methods to add or remove elements. The BlockingCollection object can become corrupted if you change the underlying collection directly.

We also have the implementation itself [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#62f5ef44f280acbf#references) where we see 2 `SemaphoreSlim`s being used to bound the `BlockingCollection`. We can see that `BlockingCollection` wasn't built to support that, and would have to share its internal synchronization objects between the 2 instance to be able to operate correctly.

You don't really need to worry about calling `Dispose` twice, but you can simply use a lock around the `Dispose` which should only happen once and so is negligible performance wise.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you can continue to the backing store after the BlockingCollection is disposed.